# How should I add Redux to a React project created with Create-React-App?

Tags: reactjs

I created a React project with Create-React-App. The `package.json` file shows:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

How do I add Redux? What command do I run to install it into my node_modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The npm command to add `redux` is:

```
npm install --save redux
```

This will modify your `package.json` file by adding `redux` as a dependency and download the package to your `node_modules` directory.

Your `package.json` file will look something like this afterwards:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

You could also add the line with `redux` (under `dependencies`) yourself.

If you do that, you'll have to run `npm install` afterwards so that the `redux` package is added to your `node_modules`.

Comment: ok, so you don't do it by updating package.json? just install it on its own? What happens if I put this on GitHub and someone else tries to use it. They will have to install all of their own dependencies?

Comment: No, this command will update your package.json for you. You can also do it by editing your package.json yourself.

Comment: yes, that was my question :-) How do I do that. I wasn't sure what I should put in and where I should put it.